# Android Webview POST request

Tags: android, post, webview, android-webview, httprequest

I'm trying to do a post request with a WebView on Android.
After searching for days and trying dozens of things i couldn't get it work. In SWIFT it's just a few lines of code so i thought there must also be a simple way to do a post request for a webview on android.
As (for 2016) EncodingUtils and HTTPClient are deprecated this are my current approaches:

```
String url = "http://example.com/php.php";
String postData = null;

postData = "param1=" + URLEncoder.encode("1234567890", "UTF-8");

webcontent.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes());
//or
webcontent.postUrl(url, Base64.encode(postData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Both just result in a blank screen. There is just one parameter to be sent and a string containing html from the server should be received.
In addition, the php on the server returns a html-string with colored background irrespective of any input, but even this isn't displayed so maybe the whole request never reaches the server? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to make a POST request to the server ?

Comment: yes, the php file on the server should receive one parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android you **do not** use `webView` to access the content of the HTTP response. You'll need to use [HttpClient](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) for that purpose!

See this [nice tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-http-client-get-post-download-upload-multipart-request.html) which explains the fundamentals! Also see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryY7Dy3z-7Q) if you find it hard!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Finally got it :)

Comment: Do you have any demo of webview with httpClient?